# Pushing Data in TCP and flow control

Tags: tcp

When TCP uses PUSH to send packets one after the other, is flow control required?

Answer (score 1):

TCP uses flow control *at all times*. Whether the PSH flag is used is irrelevant.

When the PSH flag is set it makes the source's stack send the *pushed* segments immediately, without any waiting for more data to fill an MSS-sized segment. Also on the destination, the buffer is passed to the application without any delay, regardless of buffer fill ratio.